# How does Unity's FromToRotation work? A major part of its behavior seems undocumented

Tags: unity, rotation, quaternion

All Unity's documentation states about what `FromToRotation` does is:

> Creates a rotation which rotates from fromDirection to toDirection.

This seems to leave a major part undefined - what about the other axes?

I can't help but think of the saying - If it isn't documented, the behavior is undefined.

And there seems to be no documentation of what happens to the rest of the axes. Theoretically you could spin them around `toDirection` as much as you'd like and still get what you were promised.

So, what exactly happens to the other axes when you use `FromToRotation`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FromToRotation` chooses the shortest possible rotation that maps `fromDirection` to `toDirection`.

That is, the rotation about the axis

```
axis = Vector3.Cross(fromDirection, toDirection);
```

through an angle of

```
angleRadians = Mathf.Acos(Vector3.Dot(
                  fromDirection.normalized, 
                  toDirection.normalized
               ));
```

This does become indeterminate if the two directions are exactly opposite: then a 180 degree rotation about *any* axis perpendicular to them is an equally short option, so the engine has to choose one arbitrarily.

I'm currently on mobile, so I have not tested which axis it uses in this special case, but I'd expect it uses a routine something similar to:

```
var right = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.up, fromDirection);
if (Math.Approximately(right.sqrMagnitude, 0)) {
    axis = Vector3.forward;
} else {
    axis = Vector3.Cross(fromDirection, right);
}
```

This gives the y+ axis if the two inputs are in the xz plane, the axis closest to y+ if the two inputs aren't themselves vertical, and the z+ axis if the two inputs *are* vertical. That choice is arbitrary, but seems to make sense for typical 3D navigation use cases.